# How to open tfs work item form inside ms project?

Tags: tfs, ms-project

I have ms-project plan mapped to tfs project. And i can open a work item form inside visual studio 2012. Now i need to be able to open the same work item form right inside ms-project 2013, but no such functionality was found. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to publish from MS project with an invalid field in the conflict dialog you will be able to see the work item form. May I suggest that you also have a web page open to web access and use the web view alongside the MS Project view.